# Bouncy Castle which random generator i should use?

Tags: java, android, random, bouncycastle

i have to produce same random with same seed, and cant use SecureRandom for that. Because it seeded itself even if use setseed() for it(Android). So i decided to use bouncycaste for it. what generator i should use? i'm very confused about that. i didnt find document (like guide). thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You allege that `SecureRandom` in Android ignores your specified seed? (A) That is contrary to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom#SecureRandom(byte%5B%5D)), and (B) that makes no sense. Provide evidence.

Comment: Hey Basil thank you for your answer. as described at the link [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom#setSeed(byte[])) you cannot directly seed SecureRandom class. _The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed._ i created two different SecureRandom object and want to create same output with same seed. I can do this with Random class but cannot do with SecureRandom. SecureRandom seeded itself.

Comment: I linked the constructor taking an argument for the seed. Javadoc says: *The SecureRandom instance is seeded with the specified seed bytes.*

Answer (score 0):

## Pass seed to constructor

Your assertion that `SecureRandom` ignores your specified seed is incorrect. At least not in Java. (I do not do Android work.)

To quote the [constructor of `SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)):

> The SecureRandom instance is seeded with the specified seed bytes.

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom#SecureRandom(byte%5B%5D)) says the same.

Here is some example code.

Define the seed.

```
byte[] seed = { 42 , 7 } ;
```

Pass the seed to the constructor.

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom( seed ) ;
```

Produce an output.

```
byte[] x = new byte [ 4 ] ;
sr.nextBytes( x ) ;
```

Run that code three separate times. We get the same output each time, as expected, given the same seed.

> [20, -102, -10, -126]
>
> [20, -102, -10, -126]
>
> [20, -102, -10, -126]

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/bTIkGR).

In your comments you mention the [`SecureRandom#setSeed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html#setSeed(byte%5B%5D)) method. As you mentioned, that method is clearly documenting as using the seed you specify but in conjunction with the existing seed:

> The seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed.

I grant that `setSeed` is a poor name for that method given that it does not merely replace the state of a single member field. But your specified seed is not ignored.

If you want repeatable results with `SecureRandom`, specify a seed via constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, as you said, the seed is not ignored, but unlike any java platform, things work a little differently in android. Unfortunately, you can't get the same random with the same seed directly. Actually my question starts exactly here. :)

Comment: @root99 So you are claiming that `new SecureRandom( seed ) ` will *not* produce repeatable results in Android despite doing so in Java? If so, I suggest you say that explicitly and clearly in your Question, with example code to demonstrate. Proving that point is fundamental to justifying your Question.

Comment: Yes, totally .it's because about providers. when you are eclipse or developing for desktop etc. you are probably using SUN for provider except at Android. Android use AndroidOpenSSL for this component. And you cant directyly seed this.  _The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed._   [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getProvider--)

Comment: @root99 Not to beat a dead horse, but you have not yet acknowledged *the constructor method* rather than the `setSeed` method. Does the *constructor* method in Android fail to provide repeatable results despite doing so in Java as I demonstrated in the Answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no, secure random seeding itself again. Android fail to provide repeatable results.